# Python BeautifulSoup: How to find all lowest-level divs (divs which don't contain nested divs)?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a complex HTML document that has nested `<div>` tags, such as the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            <p>1. Get this div!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <div>
                <div id="three">
                    <p>2. Get this div!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="four">
                <p>3. Get this div!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I am attempting to use the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div_list = soup.find_all('div')
```

However, the code above only gets the topmost level divs, which means it will return only divs with ids "one" and "two". **However, I would like to use BeautifulSoup to return a list of divs with ids "one", "three", and "four". How can I accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly check whether any of the found divisions has more divisions inside:

```
[d for d in soup.findAll('div') if not d.find('div')]
#[<div id="one"><p>1. Get this div!</p></div>, 
# <div id="three"><p>2. Get this div!</p></div>, 
# <div id="four"><p>3. Get this div!</p></div>]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create a list with the desired ids, and then use `re.compile`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
ids = ['one', 'three', 'four']
results = soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'id':re.compile('|'.join(ids))})
for i in results:
 print(i)
 print('-'*20)
```

Output:

```
<div id="one">
<p>1. Get this div!</p>
</div>
--------------------
<div id="three">
<p>2. Get this div!</p>
</div>
--------------------
<div id="four">
<p>3. Get this div!</p>
</div>
--------------------
```

However, without using a list for searching, recursion can be used:

```
def get_ids(_d):
  if not any(getattr(i, '__dict__', {}).get('name') == 'div' for i in _d.__dict__['contents']):
     return _d 
  _r = [get_ids(i) for i in _d.__dict__['contents'] if getattr(i, '__dict__', {}).get('name') == 'div']
  return None if not _r else _r[0]

final_results = []
for i in [get_ids(i) for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all('div')]:
  if i not in s:
     s.append(i)

print(final_results)
```

Output:

```
[<div id="one"><p>1. Get this div!</p></div>, <div id="three"><p>2. Get this div!</p></div>, <div id="four"><p>3. Get this div!</p></div>]
```

Comment: Thank you. However, is there a way to do this without the ids?

Comment: To the OP: You should mention in the original post that the ids are not to be used for searching.